# VB.net UploadFile

Tags: vb.net, upload

I am trying to send a file up to a server using VB.net. I have found many examples exclaiming it to be simple to do but none of the examples I have found have worked.

The current one I am trying is in the following code:

```
Dim WithEvents wc As New System.Net.WebClient()
Private Sub oWord_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles oWord.DocumentBeforeClose
    Try

        Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient()
            wc.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("ehavermale", "ernie1")
            wc.UploadFile("http://192.168.95.1:83/GraphTest.txt", "C:\Users\EHovermale\Desktop\GraphTest.txt")
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error:" + ex.Message)
    End Try

    'System.IO.File.Delete("C:\Users\EHovermale\Desktop\GraphTest.txt")

    MsgBox("See Ya")
End Sub
```

When I run this program I get the Error: An Exception has occurred during a WebClient Request.

I have access to read/write files to the server I am trying to hit.

Is there another way to upload files or is something wrong with my code for this way?

Thank you!

Comment: The most likely thing I can see, without knowing what is on this server, is that you are posting to the wrong "service". Since there is not a path specified, your file will be delivered to the webserver's "Default Index", probably default.aspx or index.html. If the web server is not configured to accept file posts at this address, nothing will happen. Do you perhaps need to specify a path like?
        wc.UploadFile("http://localhost:52234/FileReceivedHandler.ashx", "C:\Users\davidr\Desktop\foo.txt")

Comment: Are you "in control" of this server? ("http://192.168.95.1:83")

Comment: I changed the path to add a file name to it, still getting the same error. I am in control of this server as well. I may be misunderstanding how this process works, I am looking for a function to send a file from my pc to be stored on our server, is this the correct method to acomplish this @DavidR

Comment: Instead of just the message, how about the entire exception? IE "ex.ToString()" (or just "ex" if VB auto-casts, can't remember).

Comment: wc.UploadFile() transmits bytes to the server using HTTP POST. There must be a server-side component (like *.PHP or *.ASPX) on the web server to accept the transmitted POSTDATA and "do" something with it. What web server is being used? Also, can you post some code from the handler?

Comment: That is my problem I wasn't aware I needed something to handle the request I thought it was sending the file itself, like a file uploader does on the web.

Comment: I think it's simple if you do it in an ASPX page. There's a control for this and the code for that control to upload and save a file to the server is really easy to implement. (I used to have to do this in classic ASP, which was a PITA) Because you're trying to do it through a different mechanism, you've got to reinvent the wheel. Is it possible for you to use an ASPX page? (The control is FileUpload)

Answer (score -1):

Since there is no HTTP service to handle the file upload, you could save the file directly using VBA's Scripting.FileSystemObject. This will work if you can access the network share from wherever your document is located. Remember that if the document is moved to another computer then this may not work.

```
Public Sub MoveFile()

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim sourceFile As String
    Dim targetFile As String

    ' You must add reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" to your document
    ' Tools > References... > scroll down the item.
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sourceFile = "C:\Users\davidr\Desktop\foo.txt"
    targetFile = "\\192.168.95.1:83\foo.txt"

    ' Test if destination file already exists
    If fso.FileExists(targetFile) Then
        MsgBox ("This file exists!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Move the file
    fso.CopyFile sourceFile, targetFile
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```